# Invalid float value error in GLSL compilation for a particular float value

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am doing OpenGL developement on PC (OpenGL version 4.6).
While compiling fragment shader I get an error for a particular float value , but not for other float values.

```
float test = 0.0008935951627790928;
```

Above code produces a compilation error

```
("Shader compile failure (0): b'Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:\\nERROR: 0:52: error(#82) Syntax error: invalid float value ERROR___FP_CONST_OVERFLOW\\nERROR: error(#273)
```

But other numbers eg below work fine.

```
float test = 0.0007933847373351455;
```

Lengths of both the numbers seem to be same. Can it be something related to representation of float by  GPU hardware?

I am using GLSL 4.6 with the below preprocessor

```
#version 460 core
```

Comment: Both examples cannot be represented exactly in a float.

Comment: But the second example works fine.Even if it can not represetanble exactly , shouldnt be it rounded to nearest float.

Comment: Be sure there's no hidden characters in the literal. Re-write all digits one by one, not copy & paste.